# Convert text column, with several formats, to date column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column, named 'ActionTime' with varchar entries of the following format, either:

```
'14/02/2016 5:05'
```

or

```
'14/02/2016 15:05'
```

I want to create a query that will return a new column with the values from ActionTime as a datetime format.
I have:

```
UPDATE `test1`
SET `newcol` = str_to_date( `ActionTime` , '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i' );
```

which works assuming there aren't dates like '4/02/2016 15:05' but only like '14/02/2016 5:05'.

Can you think of a query to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [**`%H`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for 24 hour format instead of `%h`:

```
update test1
set newcol = str_to_date(ActionTime, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i');
```